# How do I improve bevel shading without adding more geometry?

Tags: modeling, bevel

I have added an edge bevel weight on my mesh, So I wouldn't have to add more geometry and keep the mesh as clean as possible. Once I add a MatCap material on it, the corners are visible of some unclean mesh which is visible. If I add loop cuts it will clean up the topology, but it would also distort the object. So I'd like to know how to eliminate the unclean corners without adding more geometry to the mesh.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also an option of using the bevel node. [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/bevel.html)

Comment: Hi Andrei, Thanks for the info, I'm aware of the Bevel node, and will be used in the future when I update my PC.. Because I'm currently using EEVEE render engine.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 4):

There are three things that could improve the corners and shading.

1. Change *Outer Miter Type* of bevel
2. Check *Harden Normals* in Bevel Modifier
3. Enable *Autosmooth* in Mesh tab

[image]

[image: image description]

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip Jachym.

Regards.